# Python: curl -F equivalent with Requests or other

Tags: python, facebook, curl, python-requests, messenger

I want to reproduce the following curl -F request ([from the Messenger API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/image-attachment)) to send an image file and parameters to Messenger's Send API:

```
curl  \
-F recipient='{"id":"USER_ID"}' \
-F message='{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{}}}' \
-F filedata=@/tmp/shirt.png \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

I'm using Requests and I tried many, many things (including with correct recipient IDs, etc.. For instance:

```
recipient = '{"id":"USER_ID"}'
message = '{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{}}}'
files = [("recipient", recipient), ("message", message), ("filedata", open(imagePath, 'rb'))]
r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN', files=files)
```

I also tried:

```
files = {"recipient" : recipient, "message" : message, "filedata" : open(imagePath, "rb")}
```

I almost always get this response error from Messenger:

```
'{"error":{"message":"(#100) param recipient must be non-empty.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"xxxxx"}}'
```

I'm at a loss here. I'm probably misusing the Requests syntax somehow, or sending a poorly formatted string to the API, but I've read the Requests documentation and browsed through StackOverflow's questions on this and couldn't solve my issue. Thank you.

Comment: the files variables needs to be a dictionary, not an array of tuples.

Comment: If you are confident that is the issue, can you provide example code in the answer? I've already tried using a dictionary. Syntax was:
files = {"recipient" : recipient, "message" : message, "filedata" : open(imagePath, "rb")}

Comment: Thanks for posting your question. It helped me debug a similar POST request to the marketing api!

Comment: Happy to be helpful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are trying to send formdata inside the requests file kwarg, when it should be in data:

```
data = {
    'recipient': '{"id":"USER_ID"}',
    'message': '{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{}}}'
}
files = {
    "filedata": open(imagePath, 'rb')
}
r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN', data=data, files=files)
```

The one assumption is that imagePath exists.

Also in python `{}` denotes a [Set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) if it doesn't have `key:value` pairs in it, so in your answer, you are passing a Set of a single tuple, which has two items in it, the string `filedata` and a `file object`.

```
{("filedata", open(imgName, 'rb'))} # Set of tuple
{"filedata": open(imgName, 'rb')}   # dictionary
```

Comment: Hi miah, you are absolutely right, cf my own answer above. I will mark yours as correct because it looks prettier. Also, for the Messenger API in particular, file type must be specified:
files = { "filedata" : ('filename.png', open(imagePath, 'rb'), 'image/png') }

Answer (score 2):

This was the correct format:

```
imgName = "tmp/graph.png"
files = { "filedata" : ('filename.png', open(imagePath, 'rb'), 'image/png')}   
data = {
    "recipient":'{"id":"' + id + '"}',
    "message":'{"attachment":{"type":"image", "payload":{}}}'
    }

r = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN, files=files, data=data)
```

Comment: can you print imagePath?

Comment: Added to the answer. It's just the filename from the current directory. The variable name "imagePath" was misleading, I renamed it.